# Resizing and Shifting Chart Source Range VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have a table created by a macro that I use as the data to create a waterfall chart:

[image: Source Data for chart (starting point)]

I would like to offset and resize the data source range (blue - column 2) *in VBA* to cover columns 3 & 4.

The VBA code would move the 'blue selection box' to here:

[image: Resulting Source Data Range]

I don't want to reference specific cells or columns as this table could appear anywhere in a worksheet. I would like to offset + resize based on the current selection (column 2) without any manual input from a user.

Comment: What did you try so far? There are the [Range.Offset Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.Offset) and the [Range.Resize Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.resize) to offset and resize from a given range: `SourceRange.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1).Resize(ColumnSize:=2)` assuming `SourceRange` to be your original blue range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way to achieve this is using a named range that updates its address on selection change.

First, add the following code to the worksheet to update the address of the named range automatically:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
   ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="BlueRange", RefersTo:=Target
End Sub
```

Then, use "BlueRange" as the input range of your chart series to have it updated automatically on each selection change:

[image]